# manifest version number effects Facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest, google-play, facebook-sdk-3.0

In order to update my app in Google play store I had to change my version number in the Android manifest.
I updated the file from:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

to:

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0"
```

the market accepted the new apk, but Facebook log in dialog stopped showing!
each time the dialog started loading it immediately close before the user can input his username and password.
Integrated Facebook app log in stopped working as well.

I couldn't find anything in stackoverflow/google about this,
what did I do wrong?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users who might come across this problem..
The keyhash was debug key, 
I produced a release key and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your facebook app whatever you have in your device needs to be updated first. Get an update. and then run . Your issue will be resolved. This is because you are using the old version. You might have not checked what should happen if the app gets an upgrade in the code.

Comment: it doesn't work with the Facebook app installed and without it. I found something here about needing a new hash key for Facebook app hen uploading to the market so I'll try that.

Comment: OK, the keyhash was debug key, I produced a release key and it solved the problem, thank you!